# Tablet(iPad/Android)-Server Communication Protocol

Tags: android, ipad, client-server, protocols, communication

I am going to build a client-server application. The client here is an iPad (or an android-based) tablet. The server is a normal pc. Both the clients and the server are connected to the same network (using WiFi).

Is there a standard way (protocol) for communication between the clients and the server? Are there any framework that can be used to ease this communication?

Thank you

Comment: Re this very old question.  From 2015 onwards, you simply use a "BAAS" (gamesparks, parse, anything like that).

Answer (score 6):

The answer depends by what you define by "server", "client", and "protocol".

Technically, the answer is "yes"; from a practical standpoint the framework you are looking for is called "socket", but regarding the protocol things may get complicated.

A protocol is a syntax structure governing data exchange, i.e., a set of rules you use to request/provide a service (see [the IETF website](http://www.ietf.org/download/rfc-index.txt)  for a list of standard ones).
Sockets, on the other hand, provide you merely a communication channel to bring bytes from one side to another and, on top of which, you are required to implement the protocol.
The good news is that socket are language independent and you can send messages between heterogeneous devices (ipad/android/linux/windows).

Using sockets in java is easy (I am making it very short here)

server side

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port);
Socket s = ss.accept();
InputStream is = s.getInputStream();
```

client side

```
Socket s = new Socket("server.address", port); // same port as above
OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
```

When you write something using *os.write()* the same bytes will be read by *is.read()*.
**What** you write on *os* is the implementation of your protocol.

This topic is covered (for java language) quite well by "Thinking in Enterprise java" by Bruce Eckel, you can [access the digital edition](http://www.javareference.com/books/freebooks/TIE/TIEJv1.1.htm) for free.
In C/C++/Objective C things are more complicated but you can easily google for tutorials.

Each service defines its own protocol and you should decide if one of the existing will do or you have to define your own, depending on which service you want to implement between the two devices.

If, as in the standard approach, the PC plays the role of server and clients want to retrieve information from it, you might want to consider installing a (very) lightweight web server and access data using *HTTPUrlConnection*. This is a wrapper for a socket with HTTP protocol management already implemented.
Beware, this is for Java; there is no "standard framework equivalent" for C/C++, I honestly have no idea about objective C.

Please, be also aware of the following:

- If client and servers has different architectures binary data exchange may get painful, better define your protocol as a sequence of strings (like SMTP) and encode/decode binaries using base64 or some other method you may want to implement
- In order to link the two sockets client has to know the server IP address; if you are running DHCP on your WIFi network then you also need to implement a discovery phase for your service

As a last side note: "client" and "server" are just labels you put on communicating entities depending on who is requesting a service/information (client) and who is providing it (server). Communication is in reality symmetrical and you can use the same structures/functions/code on both endpoints.

Comment: Thanks Dario for the nice answer